# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "anschlagen" und "attackieren"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> Am vergangenen Montag wurden zwei Männer in Bosnien attackiert.
>
> Am vergangenen Montag wurden zwei Männer in Bosnien angeschlagen.

Beides bedeutet im Internetswörterbuch "to attack". Ich möchte gerne wissen, was der Unterschied dazwischen ist und wann man sie verwendet.

Comment: Luther konnte Thesen an der Kirchentür *anschlagen*. Auf die Männer in Bosnien kann *ein Anschlag verübt* werden, wenn sie jemand *attackiert*. Ein Fußballspieler kann ausgewechselt werden, weil er *angeschlagen* ist. Aber seit den Römern werden hoffentlich nur noch sehr selten Menschen *angeschlagen* (an Kreuze nämlich). (Will sagen, die 2. Variante wird nie verwendet, weil sie schlicht falsch ist.)

Comment: @BMWurm - klingt wie die Grundlage einer Antwort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Attackieren* ist das übernommene Fremdwort (wahrscheinlich aus dem Französischen), das dasselbe bedeutet wie auf Englisch oder Französisch. Ein fast vollständiges Synonym ist *angreifen.* Man attackiert *jemanden* oder *etwas* wie zum Beispiel einen Gegner oder eine Frontlinie.

> Wir attackieren den Gegner aus allen Richtungen.
>
> Der Verurteilte attackierte zwei Unbekannte in der Fußgängerzone mit einem Küchenmesser.

*Anschlagen* ist kein Synonym. Es hat eine Vielzahl von Bedeutungen, aber *angreifen* ist nicht darunter. Die Meisten lassen sich auf *an etwas schlagen* zurückführen. So kann man zum Beispiel:

- Töne auf einem Klavier *anschlagen,*
- ein Inserat am Schwarzen Brett *anschlagen,*
- beim Schwimmen am Ende der Bahn *anschlagen,*
- eine Taste auf der Tastatur *anschlagen,*
- etwas mit einem Nagel an die Wand *anschlagen,*
- beim Anschlag einen Ball *anschlagen* (wie Aufschlag).

Außerdem können:

- Medikamente *anschlagen,* wenn sie wirken,
- ein Erreger, eine Krankheit oder eine Blessur den Körper *anschlagen,*
- ein Hund bellend *anschlagen,* oder
- früher Jäger oder Soldaten eine Waffe *anschlagen.*

Keine dieser Bedeutungen kann *einen Anschlag verüben* und damit *attackieren* bedeuten; das vermag nur das Substantiv. (Alle Bedeutungen findest du natürlich [im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anschlagen).)